# Positioning of elements in a flex layout

Tags: css, flexbox

I need help laying out my html with css `flexbox` (I hope this *is* doable with `flexbox`).
I have a `Container` with a variable amount of images. `Image` can be either landscape or portrait orientation. If image is landscape (Image 1) - it will occupy one 'row'. If image is portrait - there are two cases:

1. If there is one portrait image in a 'row' (either it's the last image, or the next one is landscape) - then Image 2 should be centered on the 'row'.
   [image: Scenario 1]
2. If there are two successive portrait images - I'd like them to both fit into one 'row' 
   [image: Scenario 2]

Pls note, that the 'rows' are an abstract notion here. I don't want to use css `grid` (unless there are absolutely no other options).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a flexbox in combination with the `justify-content: center;` and `flex-wrap: wrap;` should achieve the exact effect you are looking for.

Please see the two code snippets below for the two examples. I have used multiple coloured `div` with a width and height to simulate the horizontal and vertical image types you referred to.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  padding: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
}

.horizontal {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.vertical {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="horizontal">Image 1</div>
  <div class="vertical">Image 2</div>
</div>
```

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 100px;
  border: 2px black solid;
  padding: 1em;
  justify-content: center;
}

.horizontal {
  background: yellow;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}

.vertical {
  background: green;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100px;
}

#blue {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex">
  <div class="horizontal">Image 1</div>
  <div class="vertical">Image 2</div>
  <div class="vertical" id="blue">Image 3</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with `align-items: center` and `flex-wrap:wrap`:

```css
.flex{
    width: 220px;
    display:flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.flex img{
    border: solid 4px #efefef;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<h3>Example 1</h3>
<div class="flex">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/220/60">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/110/120">
</div>
<h3>Example 2</h3>
<div class="flex">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/220/60">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/120">
    <img src="https://placekitten.com/100/120">
</div>
```

Comment: Unlike `justify-content: center;` - your solution makes images aligned left inside the container. I may have not voiced that requirement, but that's an unwanted side-effect.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve this using the same grid system as Bootstrap using class like `container`, `row`, `col`:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
}

.align-center {
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.image1 {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: red;
}

.image2,
.image3 {
  width: 250px;
  height: 500px;
}

.image2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.image3 {
  background-color: blue;
}

.image1,
.image2,
.image3 {
  border: solid #000 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container align-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col image1">
      <h1>image1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-center">
    <div class="col image2">
      <h1>image2</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


<div class="container align-center">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col image1">
      <h1>image1</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-center">
    <div class="col image2">
      <h1>image2</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col image3">
      <h1>image3</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```